# How to run and render gym Atari environments in real time, instead of sped up?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, openai-gym, atari-2600

Currently when I render any Atari environments they are always sped up, and I want to look at them in normal speed. I am using Gym Atari with Tensorflow, and Keras-rl on Windows. The language is python.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow late, but run on this cause i was looking for an answer myself.
What I did was to sleep before every step for 1/fps. Something like:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(0.0416) (24 fps)
env.step(action)
```